# Delphi Timer Issue

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var  ff : integer;
begin

  for ff := 0 to 32 do
    If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff] then
    begin
       sndPlaySound('cashregister.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault);
    end
    else
    begin
       SendClick(451,541);
    end;

end;
```

Can anyone spot a reason to why this would be working incorrectly?
Its triggering SendClick() when it shouldn't be... is there a reason why the if and else is not working ?

```
 for i := 0 to 32 do
   If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[i] then
     sndPlaySound('cashregister.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault);
   end;
```

Is in a completely different timer... and plays the sound when it should... so the condition is returning valid when it should be..I'm almost positive it has to be something with the `ELSE` because i can do this....

```
  if f1 = 0 then
    SendClick(451,541);
  for ff := 0 to 32 do
    If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff] then 
    begin
      sndPlaySound('cashregister.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault);
      f1 := 1;
    end;
```

and it will stop clicking after the condiition has returned true one time but wont start back up again...

so i know `CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff]` is working perfectly fine ...I have not had sleep and I'm sorry if this is confusing to you guys but I don't know why you would need any further code then the first snippet ive posted to tell me whats wrong...

Now if you guys would like the ARRAYS here...

```
  CardArray[2] := '2';
  CardArray[3] := '3';
  CardArray[4] := '4';
  CardArray[5] := '5';
  CardArray[6] := '6';
  CardArray[7] := '7';
  CardArray[8] := '8';
  CardArray[9] := '9';
  CardArray[10] := '10';
  CardArray[11] := 'J';
  CardArray[12] := 'Q';
  CardArray[13] := 'K';
  CardArray[14] := 'A';
  SuiteArray[99] := 'c';
  SuiteArray[100] := 'd';
  SuiteArray[104] := 'h';
  SuiteArray[115] := 's';
  PlayArray[0] := '22';
  PlayArray[1] := '33';
  PlayArray[2] := '44';
  PlayArray[3] := '55';
  PlayArray[4] := '66';
  PlayArray[5] := '77';
  PlayArray[6] := '88';
  PlayArray[7] := '99';
  PlayArray[8] := '1010';
  PlayArray[9] := 'JJ';
  PlayArray[10] := 'QQ';
  PlayArray[11] := 'KK';
  PlayArray[12] := 'AA';
  PlayArray[13] := 'AK';
  PlayArray[14] := 'AQ';
  PlayArray[15] := 'AJ';
  PlayArray[16] := 'A10';
  PlayArray[17] := 'KA';
  PlayArray[18] := 'QA';
  PlayArray[19] := 'JA';
  PlayArray[20] := '10A';
  PlayArray[21] := 'KQ';
  PlayArray[22] := 'KJ';
  PlayArray[23] := 'K10';
  PlayArray[24] := 'QK';
  PlayArray[25] := 'QJ';
  PlayArray[26] := 'Q10';
  PlayArray[27] := 'JK';
  PlayArray[28] := 'JQ';
  PlayArray[29] := 'J10';
  PlayArray[30] := '10K';
  PlayArray[31] := '10Q';
  PlayArray[32] := '10J';
```

so for example lets say do this...

```
NewValue := 2;
NewValue3 := 2;
```

`CardArray[NewValue] +  CardArray[NewValue3]` would = 22

now lets check the play array for 22

with a for loop

```
for ff := 0 to 32 do
 if PlayArray[ff] = CardArray[NewValue] +  CardArray[NewValue3] then
begin
dowhatever...
end;
```

.... is this a valid explanation of whats going on now do you guys understand what the for loop is doing?

Comment: If you keep posting it, we'll keep closing it

Comment: And as for your question, if the condition tests true, then the first branch will be taken, otherwise the second branch will be taken

Comment: @david you closed it before...whats wrong with it i restated my question so people could understand please explain..

Comment: What's wrong with it? For starters, it's not a timer issue. Next, you haven't described what's wrong. What values did you expect to be in the arrays and variables? What values are there instead? How did those values get there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi timer issue yet again...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819017/delphi-timer-issue-yet-again)

Comment: @david also....i know that.. but its not working like that i know for a fact when it should be not clicking and it still clicks

Comment: Bryan, this question is probably going to get closed. What you should do is go back to the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819017/delphi-timer-issue-yet-again) and **edit it** to add the missing information. Describe what's wrong. All you say is that your program is clicking when it shouldn't be. We can already tell you why it's doing that — the condition you're checking is evaluating to `False`. Duh. But we have no idea why it *shouldn't* evaluate to that because we don't know what's in those variables or what they mean. And remember, it's not a timer issue.

Comment: Relax, meditate, reread your question and think - is it possible to answer the question for anyone without telepathy ability?

Comment: @Rob it is a duplicate...that one was closed...also.. its clear what its doing ...you expect everything from my source? its simply comparing a 2 different sections of 1 array with one section of another array....and checking if there the same...how can you not understand that?

Comment: If you edit the original question to include the requisite information, I'll vote to re-open it, I'll encourage others to do the same, and I'll even vote it up. But so far, neither the previous question nor this one has enough information to answer anything. We *know* your code adds two array values and compares the sum to another array value. We can *infer* that the sum does not equal the third value since the `else` branch gets taken. But we cannot tell you *why* the values aren't equal because we don't know *what* they are or *how* they got there. Use your debugger to investigate.

Comment: @Bryan Perhaps there's a bug in Delphi. Perhaps the condition is true and Delphi is choosing the wrong branch. Do you think that is likely? No, me neither. So if you want to understand why it's choosing a particular path look at the values of the variables and the answer will become clear. Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: Voted to re-open because it's now clear what the Q is.

Comment: This is still a very unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
Play := False;
Cards := CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3];
for ff := 0 to 32 do begin
  if Cards=PlayArray[ff] then begin
    Play := True;
    break;
  end;
end;
if Play then begin
  ContinuePlaying;//I've got great cards
end else begin
  Fold;//I've got a hand full of bus tickets and have to fold
end;
```

You want to play your cash register sound if any single one of the 33 options matches, otherwise you click the fold button.

I've moved the `CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3]` code out of the loop because it evaluates the same every time round and that was just confusing the heck out of us all!

Does this to it?

Comment: +1 for moving stuff out of the loop AND for your psychic abilities figuring out what @Bryan actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Bryan Are you really trying to write a poker bot for online poker play?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to make clear - just didn't give the code for it.

Comment: @Uwe I guess in this case, the OP probably needed it spelled out in code. I did give you a +1 if it's any consolation!!!

Comment: @Bryan: Psychic abilities are rare. Try right question to get right answer :).

Answer (score 2):

The sndPlaySound is taking some time to return.

So you should disable the timer during the loop:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
ff : integer;
 begin
   Timer2.Enabled := false;
for ff := 0 to 32 do
If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff] then
   begin
   sndPlaySound('cashregister.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault);
   end
else
   begin
   SendClick(451,541);
   end;
   Timer2.Enabled := true;
end;
```

And... what is strange with your code that you're looping into 33 values, with SendClick or sndPlaySound for each value... I guess your code will never work as such...

Edit: here is a modified version - perhaps it's what you want to have:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
ff : integer;
 begin
   Timer2.Enabled := false;
   try
     for ff := 0 to 32 do
     If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff] then
     begin
       sndPlaySound('cashregister.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault);
       exit; // value found
     end;
     // not found
     SendClick(451,541);
   finally  
     Timer2.Enabled := true;
   end;
  end;
```

Comment: Nope, with the `SND_ASYNC` flag, the function returns immediately.

Comment: +1 for disabling the timer. Most timer events should do this.  So the answer has merit, despite the problems in the question.

Comment: @Chris I discovered today that if the handler for a timer takes more than the timer interval, nothing happens other than timer events!! I'm sure I knew this once before but have clearly forgotten.

Comment: If you call 'Application.ProcessMessages' in the handler though, there'll be re-entry.

Comment: @Chris, most timer events don't need to disable the timer because no new timer event can arrive until the thread checks for more messages. Unless playing a sound triggers message-handling, there's no need to disable the timer.

Comment: @David yes I am... lol Its kind of a big project to get into after not coding for a while(last thing i coded was to monitor network connections and save the ips and stuff into a database and that was around 6 or 7 months ago... and yes your solution worked

Comment: @Bryan Isn't it against the rules to use a bot?

Comment: @David theres alot worse going on then me making a bot...people are creating like 10132321 accounts going to a play money table with each account till the table is full of there accounts and calling a bet of 999 (of there 1000 buyin) and and reraising with the recieving account and folding on every account that called the bet over and over and over...atleast the way ill be obtaining my chips will be valid compaired to them ruining the economy by creating more chips...

Comment: procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
ff : integer;
Play : Boolean;
Cards : String;
begin
Play := False;
Cards := CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3];
for ff := 0 to 32 do begin
  if Cards=PlayArray[ff] then begin
    Play := True;
    break;
  end;
end;
if Play then begin
  ContinuePlaying;//I've got great cards
end else begin
Fold;//I've got a hand full of bus tickets and have to fold
end;
end;
edit your snippet with that...

Comment: @Bryan My answer tries to strip away some of the details and focus on the logic. @A.Bouchez's answer is correct and pre-dated mine. @Uwe also got the answer in my view. Just accept one of them. Someone should get the rep!!!

Comment: @David i accepted your solution..sorry about the hastle lol and all the comments and stuff im just getting use to this...also why are you using the guys name from king of queens ... why not just use your first name Joe?

Comment: @bryan sorry but I'm not in america and don't have a TV so I don't get the Heffernan King of queens reference!

Comment: @Bryan sorry that I didn't get the rep! :)

Answer (score 1):

NewValue or NewValue3 does not contain what you think it contains (and no one can guess what that is because there's no indication of where the values come from).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not aware of the fact that the if clause is executed for all values ff from 0 to 32. So you have 33 checks and 33 times either the sound or the click.

My psychic power tells me that you are looking for the sum of the both CardArray values being equal to one value inside PlayArray and then playing a sound or making a click when no match is found. But that is not what you programmed.

Comment: I am aware that it is executed 33 times... NewValue and NewValue3 are constantly being updated...

Comment: They're being updated _while_ the loop is running?  How does that work?

Comment: because newvalue's are global variables being updated by a function inside a seperate timer.... the functions read a address in memory and save the values read as newvalue's is this starting to make sense?

Comment: Even if these values are updated from a second timer, there is only one timer event executed at a time. The other timer events are still in the message queue until this timer event is finished. So as your PlayArray values are all different, you will get at most one sound and at least 32 clicks during this timer event.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the line:

```
If CardArray[NewValue] + CardArray[NewValue3] = PlayArray[ff] then
```

Is not evaluating to true when you expect it to. It is evaluating to false, so the sendclick is executed.

Set a breakpoint on the 'If' in the debugger, look at the values you are adding, are they what you expect?