# Having difficulty with Delphi if statements

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Note: Do not edit the layout of this code! (See answer below for the reason)

```
procedure TForm1.ReadCardTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit1.Text)),1);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit3.Text)),2);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit2.Text)),3);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit4.Text)),4);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit5.Text)),5);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit6.Text)),6);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit7.Text)),7);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit8.Text)),8);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit9.Text)),9);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit10.Text)),10);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit11.Text)),11);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit12.Text)),12);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit13.Text)),13);
ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit14.Text)),14);
if NewValue = 0 then
Image1.Hide;
Image2.Hide;
if NewValue > 0 then
Image1.Show;
Image2.Show;
UpdateCardImage(NewValue,NewValue2,'Image1');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue3,NewValue4,'Image2');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue5,NewValue6,'Image3');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue7,NewValue8,'Image4');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue9,NewValue10,'Image5');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue11,NewValue12,'Image6');
UpdateCardImage(NewValue13,NewValue14,'Image7');
end;
```

For some reason the second image i try and hide... wont hide... I can comment out the first one and the second one will hide whats going on here?

Comment: Please don't edit the layout of this code. As Golez pointed out, the answers don't make so much sense once the layout of the code in the Q is fixed.

Comment: Are you the Bryan that asked the Delphi Timer question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820118/delphi-timer-issue) two days ago? You may not be aware of this, but you do not need to create a new account for every question you ask. Simply login with the one you used before. It also ensures that you do not lose any rep you gained previously. You can merge your current and previous accounts, if you need help with that, ask the moderators. They should be able to help.

Comment: This is a beginner Pascal question, not Delphi.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I indented your code to reflect the meaning of the `if` statements. Hopefully it will now be clear to you what is going on. I recommend that you start indenting your code yourself!

```
procedure TForm1.ReadCardTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ReadCard2(StrToInt(PChar('$' + Form2.Edit1.Text)),1);
    //etc.
    if NewValue = 0 then
        Image1.Hide;
    Image2.Hide;
    if NewValue > 0 then
        Image1.Show;
    Image2.Show;
    UpdateCardImage(NewValue,NewValue2,'Image1');
    //etc.
end;
```

Presumably what you mean is:

```
    if NewValue = 0 then
    begin
      Image1.Hide;
      Image2.Hide;
    end;
    if NewValue > 0 then
    begin
      Image1.Show;
      Image2.Show;
    end;
```

But, assuming that `NewValue` is never negative, then I would use the `Visible` property which is a short-hand for `Show`/`Hide`:

```
Image1.Visible := NewValue>0;
Image2.Visible := Image1.Visible;
```

This *declarative* approach typically results in clearer, more expressive code. Additionally it allows you to express concisely the fact that the visibility of these controls is tied together.

Comment: Please do *not* edit the code in the original question. It will make less clear what the context of the question actually was. Just copy the code to your answer if you need to make a point.

Comment: @Golez Is this more to your liking?

Comment: Although I would put the begin on a new line, but that's a matter of taste. ;)

Comment: @Golez I realis that my standard of always using begin and always on the same line as the if is unusual. I try to fit in with the rest of the world here, even though I do it my way at work!

Comment: Ah, but I also like what's called the "hanging" begin. Let's just all agree not to push eachother's coding standards on one another.

Comment: @Marjan I'm not trying to push coding standards on anyone. I edited my question to fit what seems to be the most common Delphi formatting. I wouldn't write the if the way I have done in this answer!

Comment: @David: I know. I wasn't implying you or @GolezTrol were. I *did* notice the smiley in @GolezTrols' comment. My comment was more directed at other people wanting to chime in on something which can lead to religous coding standard wars. I have been there before and didn't like it.

Comment: I forgot to wrap the bottom section thats what the problem was haha

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use

```
begin
  Image1.Show;
  Image2.Show;
end;
```

`begin` and `end` tell the compiler that the statements belong together. In your code, the second is always shown, while the first is only shown when the `if` expression returns `True`.

Comment: ive tryed doing that.. still hides whichever one is there first and not the second even if its wrapped with begin and end...

Comment: @Bryan That doesn't sound plausible. In @Golez's code, both `Show` method calls will execute.

Comment: You will need to apply that to the 'hide' part of your code too. All lines that belong to each of the `if`s (and `while`, `for` and other control flow statements too) should be enclosed in a `begin`..`end` block.

Comment: Where I work, our standard is that an `if`, `else`, `for` or `while` statement must be followed by a `begin`. If only we could have a Delphi that used Modula-2's `IF THEN END`!!

Comment: You mean like Visual Basic? ;)

Comment: @Golez I'm thinking specifically of Modula-2 which does not distinguish between single and compound statements. An `IF` is terminated by an `END` no matter how many statements are contained. Likewise `FOR` and `WHILE`. I'm using upper case because Modula-2 was case-sensitive. It did look as though you were shouting a lot though!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using PChar()? It is not necessary there.

Comment: Welcome. You are right, but not an answer to the question. It would be better if you add this as a comment to the question and not as an answer as you did now.

Comment: it is necessary because the function ReadCard2 Uses ReadProcessMemory and address's need to be formated with $

Comment: I see. But this code will work too: 
ReadCard2(StrToInt('$' + Form2.Edit1.Text),1);

Answer (score 1):

This why you should use a code formatter. It would have made it easy to spot the problem.